# Issues during submitting Delphi POST request to Piwik

Tags: delphi, post, indy, matomo

I try to submit Delphi POST request to Piwik as descibed here: http://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/reference/#toc-advanced-bulk-tracking-requests.

My Delphi implementation is shown below:

```
  FPiwikRequest := '';
  FPiwikRequest := FPiwikRequest + Format('?cvar=PAGE_%s&', ['something']);
  FPiwikRequest := FPiwikRequest + Format('action_name=6new_%s&', ['ActionPage']);
  FPiwikRequest := FPiwikRequest + Format('idsite=%d&', [3]);
  FPiwikRequest := FPiwikRequest + Format('rec=%d&', [1]);
  FPiwikRequest := FPiwikRequest + Format('url=%s&', ['http://localhost/analytics/index45.html']);
  FPiwikRequest := FPiwikRequest + Format('urlref=%s&', ['http://localhost/analytics/index13.html']);
  FPiwikRequest := FPiwikRequest + Format('_id=%s&', ['231e3849e534a3c6']);
  FPiwikRequest := FPiwikRequest + Format('rand=%d', [Random(1000)]);
  json := SO;
  json.O['requests'] := SA([]);
  json.A['requests'].S[0] := FPiwikRequest;
  json.A['requests'].S[1] := FPiwikRequest_2;
  json.S['token_auth'] := 'ffff9fb80b9558e4529fe96902dffff';
  FPiwikRequest := json.AsString;
  HTTPClient.POST(PIWIK_HOME + FPiwikRequest, response); //HTTPClient => idHTTP class
```

After submitting the request Piwik script processes only last request json.A['requests'].S[1] from the submitted bulk requests.

**When I submit same bulk request from Python then the Piwik process both requests from the submitted bulk requests.*

Do you have any ideas about such Delphi POSTing behavior?

Comment: What class is HTTPClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, for this post. Answer is simple :) and one of the approaches is shown below.

So, you should add Params to method POST

```
LRequestParams := TStringStream.Create();
try
  LRequestParams.WriteString(FPiwikRequest);  
  HTTPClient.POST(PIWIK_HOME, LRequestParams, response);
finally
  LRequestParams.Free;   
end;
```